# cron log shows old cron job being executed?

Tags: linux, cron

I am running a test script where in a loop of 800, two crontab scripts create new crontab in a duration of 5 seconds.

Eg.

```
while [ "$counter" -lt 800 ]; do
    crontab -r
    create_crontab_1.sh >> cr_log.log
    sleep 5;
    create_crontab_2.sh>> cr_log.log
    (( counter++ ))
done
```

Now

create_crontab_1.sh->
CRONLINE="*/2 * * * * /scratch/test1.sh >/dev/null 2>&1"
( crontab -l 2>/dev/null ; echo "${CRONLINE}" ) | crontab -

create_crontab_2.sh->
    crontab cron_file.txt

cron_file.txt ->
    * * * * * sleep 2; /scratch/test3.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
    * * * * * sleep 3; /scratch/test4.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

/var/log/cron log:

crond[25583]: (user_name) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/)
 CROND[29339]: (root) CMD (sleep 3; /abc/test3.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
 CROND[29340]: (root) CMD (sleep 2; /abc/test4.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
 crontab[29345]: (user_name) LIST ()
 CROND[29353]: (user_name) CMD (/abc/test1.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
 crontab[29365]: (user_name) REPLACE ()

Even when crontab with test1.sh gets overwritten in 5 seconds, why does test1.sh comes in cron log, and can be seen getting invoked every 2 mins (as it is scheduled to run every 2 mins) ??
Also does it have anything to do with CPU clock?

Comment: `create_crontab_1.sh` and `create_crontab_2.sh` does not appear to be shell scripts. The loop removes the crontab (with `-r`) and then it runs these text files. You should see errors, yes?

Comment: /var/log/cron output

Comment: The log you've included shows a `LIST` entry towards the end. I'm assuming this is done by you running `crontab -l` on the command line as there is no such command in the script. There are no timestamps in the log, so it hard to tell if the log is relevant at all.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the commands inside your loop, and reorder them a bit, the repeating part is this:

```
while ... do
    create_crontab_2.sh >> cr_log.log
    (( counter++ ))
    crontab -r
    create_crontab_1.sh >> cr_log.log
    sleep 5;
done
```

What `create_crontab_2.sh` does to edit the `crontab` is undone by the following `crontab -r`. Only what is set in the crontab by `create_crontab_1.sh` is there during the sleep. As changing the crontab is likely to be fast, it's not likely that `cron` is going to see the rules set by `create_crontab_2.sh` pretty much at all.

Comment: I have modified the loop logic to following: